# Category of topological pairs

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, notation, category-theory, convention

Is there a *standard* abbreviation for the category of topological pairs?
I have searched for it in vain.

Comment: I've seen $\mathrm{Top}^2$ a couple of times (although this maybe confused with $\mathrm{Top} \times \mathrm{Top}$).

Comment: One more variant: $(Top,Top)$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: But $\mathbf{Top}^2$ would included all arrows $f:A\to X$, wouldn't it? The category of pairs has only inclusions $i:A\hookrightarrow X$

Comment: Yes I know that this terminology is confusing, but I've seen it.

Comment: I think I've seen also $\mathrm{Top}_2$.

Comment: A teacher of mine used $\mathrm{Top}^{[2]}$ (with the advantage of the distinction with the category $\mathrm{Top}^{\mathbf 2}$ of arrows). But I doubt it's *standard*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is any such thing, it must be $\mathbf{Top}^2$ (found e.g. in Gray's Homotopy theory).